# 2D drawing canvas (JPanel) using Java how to scale drawing?

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I'm trying to write their own engine for drawing using `Java`.

I have problem when I resize `JFrame` with my drawing canvas `JPanel`.

The code:

```
public class DrawingCanvas extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);


        image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        clear(g2); // fill background white

        int wSize = actx.getMap().getW(); //ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE Width
        int hSize = actx.getMap().getH(); //ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE Height

        //calculate ascpect ration
        double wVypocet = (double) this.getWidth() / (double) wSize;
        double hVypocet = (double) this.getHeight() / (double) hSize;

        double min = Math.min(wVypocet, hVypocet);

        g2.scale(wVypocet, hVypocet);

        for (int i = 0; i < actx.getMap().gameMap.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < actx.getMap().gameMap[0].length; j++) {
                g2.setColor(actx.getMap().gameMapColorMap[i][j]); //set up my color
                g2.drawRect(i, j, 1, 1); //fill 1 pixel
            }
        }

            g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
   }

}
```

When I change size of `JFrame` i get a good render or fail render:

**GOOD RENDER:** [good render image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn7uH.png)
[image]

**RENDER FAIL:**(image disturbance) [fail render image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3roy.png)
[image]

Why?

Is there any better way how to implement resize?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I upload image to stackoverflow but I can't add image to my post, because I have small "carma points".

Comment: Got it.... Hm, now I'm not so sure that my answer answers your actual problem. You might want to work on creating and posting a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool. Thanks for posting the links though, 1+.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you very much for your help, but I can't put small demo here, because I work with file. The program load data from file. I think, the problem is in `g2.drawRect(i, j, 1, 1);`. Because when I draw a simple circle at mid of canvas it's good, no problems.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 
Simple plot of chessboard also works great

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rescale an image? Draw a rescaled image from data points? If so, I believe that the image related classes have methods that help with image rescale. Note that I'm not an image expert and so I can't give chapter and verse. And regarding the chessboard, can you post a simple runnable [mcve] program that demonstrates your problem using the chessboard?

Comment: @nustauos Are you asking why you are getting the white dots on your image when you resize your window?

Comment: You're doing way way way way too much in your paintComponent method.  You should just paint.  Resizing your image should take place in a window resize method.